# is it possible to update the information_schema table in order to add leading text to column names?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to execute this SQL as root:

```
UPDATE information_schema.COLUMNS SET COLUMN_NAME = CONCAT('emp',COLUMN_NAME)  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'edsdb'
```

But get the following error:

```
SQL Error [1044] [42000]: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'information_schema'
```

These tables that I need to 'fix' the column names off have a lot of columns in them. Is it possible to do this directly in SQL?

Comment: You cannot directly modify the `information_schema` views.

Comment: No, you can't edit the system table or view. Those are read only

Comment: Thanks, is there an indirect way of doing this perhaps by creating temp tables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the MySQL documentation ([here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html)), `information_schema` contains read-only tables which are `views` so you can't change it:

> The INFORMATION_SCHEMA database contains several read-only tables.
>   They are actually views, not base tables, so there are no files
>   associated with them, and you cannot set triggers on them. Also, there
>   is no database directory with that name.

You need to use `ALTER TABLE` command instead, e.g.:

```
ALTER TABLE `edsdb` CHANGE `id` `empid` INT;
```

Answer (score 3):

> is it possible to update the information_schema table in order to add leading text to column names?

**DO NOT TRY THIS**.  Instead, update your tables to rename the columns you need to rename.

There are versions of MySQL that correctly prevent this.

There are older versions that don't. If you manage to update the system tables (actually the ones in the `mysql` schema) in one of those versions, you'll corrupt your MySQL server.

Please don't ask how I know this. :-)

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't edit the system table or view. Those are read only. But you don't need to update as well, you can just make a `SELECT` query and display the same

```
SELECT CONCAT('emp',COLUMN_NAME) as new_column_name 
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS  
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'edsdb'
```

Probably, you can consider creating a `VIEW` with the above `SELECT` statement for future